# Logical Complexity of Ultrafilters

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, computational-complexity

Good morning,

I usually really struggle with logical complexity, when I see a statement it's very difficult for me to understand if it should be $\Delta_0$ or $\Sigma_1$ or something else (in the Lévy hierarchy). Hence, I was trying to look at some usual definitions in set theory to check if my understanding of this complexity is correct. It's also pretty much impossible to find online if an answer to a question of this kind is correct, so I'm going to ask here hoping for maybe also some reference to a textbook where I can learn more?

So, for example, the statement "$f$ is a filter on $\omega$".  I would write it formally this way:
$$(f\subseteq p(\omega)) \land (\varnothing\not\in f) \land (\forall a \in f,\ \forall b\in p(\omega): a\subseteq b\to b\in f)\land(\forall a\in f,\ \forall b\in f: a\cap b\in f).$$

All the quantifiers look bounded to me, hence this is a $\Delta_0$ statement with no parameters? Am I right? And if I want to say "there is a filter on $\omega$" it would become a $\Sigma_1$ statement with no parameters(?)

Second question: now about ultrafilters. "$u$ is an ultrafilter on $\omega$" clearly means:
$$(u\ \text{is a filter on}\ \omega)\land (\forall a\in p(\omega): a\not\in u \to (\omega-a)\in u).$$
This again looks $\Delta_0$ with no parameters, to me. And "there is an ultrafilter on $\omega$" is $\Sigma_1$.

Hence again, "$u$ is a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega$" means
$$(u\ \text{is an ultrafilter on}\ \omega)\land (\forall g\in \omega\ \exists b\in u: g\not\in b).$$
And this AGAIN looks $\Delta_0$ to me! Maybe I'm doing something wrong because clearly not every statement can be $\Delta_0$...

Now, given a set $h$, we can define $[h]^2$ as the set of all subsets of $h$ with cardinality $2$, that is
$$\{s\subseteq h:\ \exists a\in s,\ \exists b\in s: a\neq b \land (\forall c\in s:\ a=c\lor b=c)\}.$$
This is again a $\Delta_0$ definition, besides the fact that now I am using $h$ as a parameter.

But then if I want to say that "$u$ is a Ramsey ultrafilter" I just say that
$$(u\ \text{is a nonprincipal ultrafilter on}\ \omega) \land (\forall s \subseteq[\omega]^2\ \exists h\in u:(s\subseteq[h]^2\lor s\cap[h]^2=\varnothing)).$$
So I would again say that this is $\Delta_0$, and "there is a Ramsey ultrafilter" is a $\Sigma_1$ statement without parameters.

Is this reasoning true? To me it looks like it shouldn't be... too many "easy complexity" formulas...

Comment: For a formula to be considered $\Delta_0$ it should be written using 1) The free parameters, 2) $\in$ 3) $=$, 4) logical connectives, 5) quantifiers that are either bounded by the free parameters, or bounded by other bound variables appearing higher in the parse tree of the formula.  Your formulas don't meet this definition, because they use defined concepts like $\emptyset, \subseteq, \cap$, a unary operator for powerset.

Comment: @ChadK well but I can also use other $\Delta_0$ concepts in a $\Delta_0$ formula, no? So for example $\varnothing$ is fine since I can define $\varnothing$ as a set $x$ such that $\forall y\in x: y\neq y$. And similarly for $\subseteq$, $\cap$ and $p$

Comment: @ChadK so instead of writing $(\varnothing\not\in f)$ I can write $(\forall x\in f\ \exists y\in\omega: y\in x)$ for example. Instead of writing $(a\subseteq b)$ I could write $(\forall x\in a: x\in b)$. Instead of writing $(a\cap b\in f)$ I can write $(\forall x\in a: x \in b\to x\in f)$...

Comment: 'y is the powerset of x' is not definable by a $\Delta_0$ formula.  'x is empty', 'x is a subset of y' and 'z is $x\cap y$' are $\Delta_0$-definable, but you have to be careful when using $\emptyset, \cap$ as function symbols that you can quantify boundedly over the extra variable you have to introduce.

Comment: @ChadK okay, but for empty, subset and intersection, in the cases I used them, it looks there are no problems, right? So my only problem is with the power set of $\omega$... can I then say that the sentences are $\Delta_0$ and $\Sigma_1$ with $p(\omega)$ as a parameter? and if I didn't wanted to use a parameter, how is the complexity of "$y$ is the power set of $x$"?

Comment: @ChadK but for example, the first "$f\subseteq p(\omega)$" I can write it as "$\forall x\in f,\ \forall y\in x: y\in \omega$" which is still $\Delta_0$ with no parameters. So the main problem is when I quantify over $p(\omega)$?

Comment: @ChadK okay sorry, maybe I get it. "$u$ is an ultrafilter on $\omega$" is $\Pi_1$ because I am quantifying once over $p(\omega)$, which I can write instead of $\forall b\in p(\omega)$ just write $\forall b$ and then $b\subseteq\omega\to ...$ So this is $\Pi_1$, the nonprincipal is also $\Pi_1$, and the Ramsey is also $\Pi_1$ because instead of writing $\forall s\subseteq[\omega]^2$ I just write $\forall s$ and then $s\subseteq[\omega^2]\to ...$ So the ones I said were $\Delta_0$ are $\Pi_1$, and the ones I said were $\Sigma_1$ are $\Sigma_2$. Would "there is no Ramsey ultrafilter" be $\Pi_1$?

Comment: I didn't mean to do the analysis for you.  I meant to say you have to be careful when using defined symbols, or else you can hide any number of unbounded quantifiers in defined symbols.  In Jech's Set Theory, he defines the language on page 5 to be based on $\in, =$, then definition 12.8 (page 163) what a $\Delta_0$ formula is, then Lemma 12.10 a list of relations that are $\Delta_0$-definable.

Comment: @ChadK thanks for the reference. I hope somebody else will help me check if what I said is correct, then.

Comment: The wikipedia page for the Levy Hierarchy contains a list of examples of various complexity. It is a good exercise to prove that their examples are actually correct.

Comment: Powerset is a $\Pi_1$ concept!